Cannot export document.xml from Word DOCX because of error
I have a docx that was saved by LibreOffice, but cannot be opened anymore because the file is corrupted. Trying to open gives me the error Dateiformatfehler an Position at ./package/source/xstor/owriteablestream.cxx:622(Zeile,Spalte) entdeckt.
When I open the docx as zip with ark and try to decompress the document.xml, I get the error error:  invalid compressed data to inflate word/document.xml and get a xml file with just 70kb instead of 700 kb it should be.
I tried to validate with OOXMLValidatorCLI.exe and got the following message:
[{"Description":"Inner exception: '<', hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character. Line 2, position 31111..","Path":{"Namespaces":{},"XPath":"","PartUri":"/word/document.xml"},"Id":"ExceptionError","ErrorType":"Schema"}]


I tried to uncompress with uncozip.exe and get the error flate: corrupt input before offset 19526
zipinfo gives the following info:
Central directory entry #9:  
---------------------------  
  
 There are an extra 16 bytes preceding this file.  
  
 word/document.xml  
  
 offset of local header from start of archive:   4034  
                                                 (0000000000000FC2h) bytes  
 file system or operating system of origin:      MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT  
 version of encoding software:                   2.0  
 minimum file system compatibility required:     MS-DOS, OS/2 or NT FAT  
 minimum software version required to extract:   2.0  
 compression method:                             deflated  
 compression sub-type (deflation):               normal  
 file security status:                           not encrypted  
 extended local header:                          yes  
 file last modified on (DOS date/time):          2024 Jan 4 11:25:14  
 32-bit CRC value (hex):                         0ab6441d  
 compressed size:                                77832 bytes  
 uncompressed size:                              871974 bytes  
 length of filename:                             17 characters  
 length of extra field:                          0 bytes  
 length of file comment:                         0 characters  
 disk number on which file begins:               disk 1  
 apparent file type:                             binary  
 non-MSDOS external file attributes:             000000 hex  
 MS-DOS file attributes (00 hex):                none  
  
 There is no file comment.

Do you have any hints how I can investigate to repair the file or is it not repairable anymore?

Please do not ask two questions about the exact same subject....  see::Can I repair/debug this corrupted DOCX or is it irretrievable destroyed?   When you have more info use the edit button below the (now closed) question, to improve the question.
